# Richtextbox Lines.Length == -1

Tags: c#, winforms, return-value

I am trying to number each line in a RichTextBox. I have gotten the number of lines using `Lines.Length`. If I start typing when it is blank that will turn to 1, but if I press backspace 2-3 times then start typing it returns 0.

*(I know pointless)* Here is the function that return the number of lines and you can see *(my failed attempt)* where I tried to compare it with the `TextLength` to correct the value.

```
private int LineCount()
{
    int textLength = MainIOControl.TextLength;
    int lineCount = MainIOControl.Lines.Length - 1;
    return (textLength == 0 && lineCount == 0) ? 0 : lineCount;
}
```

This return the correct value if you just start typing, but not if you press backspace a couple times when it is empty.

Am I simple overlooking something obvious?

Comment: What return if you press couple of times backspace, when it is empty. What do you mean by when it is empty, when the richtext box is empty or what ?

Comment: @mybirthname `Lines.Length` return 0 after pressing backspace a couple of times but 1 if you just start typing. When it is empty - When there is no text/numbers/anything in the richtextbox.

Comment: When you execute this LineCount Method ?

Comment: @mybirthname After pressing backspace a couple time then typing some letters **0**, but if I just start typing **1**.

Comment: From what I understood, you click 2 times backspace after that start writing and the method returns 0, if you directly start writing the method return 1. That means that this method is executed only on first keyboard button action. So because of that I'm asking where/when you execute this method. Sorry if I don't understand you correctly.

Comment: @mybirthname I am executing it inside the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calculating it yourself instead of using the Lines property:

```
return MainIOControl.Text.Length - MainIOControl.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty).Length;
```

This one may work better for your situation:

```
private int LineCount()
        {
            return MainIOControl.Text.Length - MainIOControl.Text.Replace("\n", string.Empty).Length + 1;
        }
```

Comment: This seems to work strangely. The first line returns **0**, the second line returns **2**, the third - **4** and the forth - **6** and it keeps incrementing like that.

Comment: See my latest change, The RichTextBox seems to not implement the correct Environment.NewLine,  plus I added one to count the starting line.   See if that helps.

Comment: Depending on the system, newlines are implemented with "\n" and sometimes with "\r\n"